# Multiline string replace inside markup tag

Tags: sed, apache-httpd, replace

I am trying to modify an `httpd.conf` file, allowing override in the `/var/www/html` directory. For simplicity's sake, let's say it looks like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    # Comment
    AllowOverride none
    # Comment
</Directory>
```

Trying to replace `AllowOverride none` with `AllowOverride All`.

I tried something like this:

```
sed -i 's/\(Directory \"\/var\/www\/html\">.*?\)AllowOverride none\(.*?<\/Directory>\)/\1AllowOverride all\2/' httpd.conf
```

It doesn't look like it catches multiple lines, so I tried some other things, such as RegEx modifiers and this: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Text-search-across-multiple-lines.html
but was unable to match the desired string.

How would one go about doing this? Solutions outside of sed are welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that what you want is to replace ONLY the `AllowOverride none` specifically in the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` block and not elsewhere. We can do that.

Short version:

```
sed -i '/^<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/^<\/Directory>/ {
    s/AllowOverride none/AllowOverride all/;
}' httpd.conf
```

This says to only apply the substitute command between the specified lines.

Remember to back up your file first, and `diff` them after to confirm you got what you wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

`sed`, being a *nix text tool, is line based. To work upon several lines, you need to take certain measures. Why doesn't

```
sed 's/AllowOverride none/AllowOverride all/' file
```

satisfy your needs?

**EDIT:** or, if you only want to change the string in that "directory" paragraph,

```
sed '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride none/AllowOverride all/' file
```

**EDIT:** With three small adaptions, you make your own script work correctly:

```
sed    's/\(Directory \"\/var\/www\/html\">.*?\)AllowOverride none\(.*?<\/Directory>\)/\1AllowOverride all\2/' file
sed -z 's/\(Directory \"\/var\/www\/html\">.*\)AllowOverride none\(.*<\/Directory>\)/\1AllowOverride all\2/' file
     ^                                       ^                        ^
```

`-z` (--null-data, separate lines by NUL characters; cf. `man sed`) makes `sed` ignore line feed chars, i.e. loads the entire file. The two `?` indicated by the carets must go away. And, be aware that the `"` don't need the escape `\` (but it doesn't hurt).